# Phone Hangs after taking Photo in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

So i've been working on a xamarin.forms mobile app and part of that envolves taking a photo, it has been working fine but suddenly yesterday the phone started to hang after taking a photo, this was with no new code changes at the time.

this is a xamarin.forms project that targets only android, running the VS2019 built in emulator on pie 9.0 API 28

I've spend many hours trying to work this out but i'm very new to mobile development and i'm at a loss on what is the cause, it seems something is flooding the nursery memory with new allocations but i can't for the life of me work out what or why, as soon as the image is taken and accepted the console starts flooding this:

```
11-07 10:08:21.691 I/.co.lilleker_i(16426): Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 8770(448KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 1623KB/3MB, paused 617us total 5.821ms
11-07 10:08:21.695 D/Mono    (16426): GC_TAR_BRIDGE bridges 1439 objects 1439 opaque 0 colors 1439 colors-bridged 1439 colors-visible 1439 xref 0 cache-hit 0 cache-semihit 0 cache-miss 0 setup 0.04ms tarjan 0.20ms scc-setup 0.14ms gather-xref 0.15ms xref-setup 0.02ms cleanup 0.06ms
11-07 10:08:21.695 D/Mono    (16426): GC_BRIDGE: Complete, was running for 15.62ms
11-07 10:08:21.695 D/Mono    (16426): GC_MINOR: (Nursery full) time 3.80ms, stw 4.91ms promoted 158K major size: 1680K in use: 912K los size: 1024K in use: 208K
```

this happens every half second and the app becomes unresponsive, i've disabled all the other code that runs after this, as such the following method is all that is run:

```
 private async Task<Byte[]> GetPhoto()
    {
        try
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ": (No Camera available.", "OK");
                return null;
            }

            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                Directory = "Sample",
                Name = "test.jpg"
            });

            if (file == null)
                return null;

            await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

            return null;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            string m = ex.Message;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The alert displays along with a path, but after that it hangs (i can't even close the alert)

The only thing i've spotted in the logs that might be an issue is the following line:

```
type=1400 audit(0.0:1494): avc: denied { link } for comm=54687265616420506F6F6C20576F72 name="PropertyStore.forms.tmp" dev="dm-1" ino=123214 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c96,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c96,c256,c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=0
```

But i can't seem to find out what that actually means. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Try to delete the folder `bin` and  `obj` both in share project and Android project .Then clean and rebuild it .

Comment: Unfortunatly that didn't help. Thanks for the suggest tho

Comment: From your code it seems that the method `GetPhoto()` will always return null even if the file is not a null value .

Comment: That's correct, it originally converted the photo to a byte array to be sent to a web api but i removed that part of the code while trying to work out what was causing the issue.

Comment: Could you share a sample which contains the issue and I will check it on my side .

Comment: Ok so in the proccess of making a sample it turns out the identical code in a new project dosn't have this issue. Which must mean something else in my project is causing the problem. Looks like i'll have to dig deeper to work this out. Thanks for the help anyhow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after being asked a sample project i created a new project and used the exact code only to find it suddenly wasn't having this issue. I spent some time trying to see what could be different only to notice the newly created project had updated xamarin.forms and xamarin.essentials packages.

After a lot of fudging with nuget i managed to get my application upgraded to use Xamarin.Essentials 1.2.0 and Xamarin.Forms 4.2.0.709249 (which is the same as the new project template uses) and the issue is now resolved.

Comment: You can accept your answer ,which will help more people .